# How to submit more than one value in ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've a question about my code. How can I submit two values? I my code I submit only one string, but I don't know how I can submit tow values in the url.

I already tried cutting the submitted request-string

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo $actual_link; ?>/pages/panel/ajaxsearch.php?user=" + str + "secondvalue" + secondval, true);

// Cut
echo stristr($_REQUEST["user"], 'secondval');
```

It works, but it's ugly.

```
<script>
    function showHint(str) {
        if (str.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo $actual_link; ?>/pages/panel/ajaxsearch.php?user=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>

<input onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
```

Comment: you can use & to separate multiple parameters in the query URL.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&` symbol for separation, like this

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo $actual_link; ?>/pages/panel/ajaxsearch.php?user=" + str + "&secondvalue" + secondval, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

With & character

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","requesturl.php?Param=value&param2=valie1&param2=foo" , true);
```

If you have php array send to request with Ajax maybe want to a function ..php array convert to Ajax query

```
$data = array('cow' => 'milk', 'php' => 'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data) ;
```

Output

```
cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
```